# How to Enable JQuery Code Assistant on Eclipse?

Tags: jquery, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

I use a clean installation of Eclipse PDT 2023-09 on Windows 10. The plugin Wild Web Development is installed and enabled. How to add support for JQuery code assistant (autocomplete)? I tried many solutions that I found on the Internet without any success. It seems all these solutions are old and don't work for this release.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same challenge too, am also running 2023-09 release, the solutions out there are too old for this release.

Then I got the clue from this (old) solution "Global Way":
https://www.riksoft.it/wikiriks/ide/eclipse-jquery-code-completion

1. Download jQuery.js
2. For this release add from file system in "Include Path" project properties

Add jQuery.js to Include Path:
[image: jquery to include path]

Auto completion on `$()`:
[image: auto completion]

Not an elegant one but works for the purpose and as I already spent (too much) time on this so I'm just happy to move on ;-)